# How to call HTML file with multiple pages in that particular file?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTMl file with multiple pages in it as show below.
How can make a call to this file from a diffrent html file with specific pageid.

Example call: index.html/pageone or page two ?

1) Index.html

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" ">

         <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">

         </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" style="overflow:scroll;">


          <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"  >
            <h1>Advertisment - Footer </h1>
         </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="pagetwo" style="overflow:scroll;">

         <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">

         </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" style="overflow:scroll;">


          <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"  >
            <h1>Advertisment - Footer </h1>
         </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you should learn a server-side templating language like PHP, or ASP.NET.

Comment: or use an ajax call to load the interested portion of the 2nd html file

Comment: if you just want to hit the id itself index.html#pageone else read comments above